# Spring Cloud RPC transport

Tags: spring-cloud

Almost every spring-cloud guide suggests Ribbon with Feign for RPC.
I wonder why Http Rest takes precedence over binary transport protocol for inner micro-services communication behind the API gateway?

What are the binary alternatives to http that support async invocation and all great features that Netflix OSS provides ? (auto-discovery, load-balancing, circuit breaker, retry policy etc.)

Thanks

Comment: One way is to use GET using Rest and then modify things using Spring Cloud Stream Rabbit.  You still get discovery etc using this method.  Load balancing and circuit breaker type functionality would defer to the RabbitMQ config.

Comment: I after lower level transport than http for micro-services inter-communication, want to eliminate http connection creation handshake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing preventing you from using binary RPC like thrift or protobuffs or msgpack with spring cloud. You can use `LoadBalancerClient.choose(<serviceId>)` to get a host and port you could supply to **any** network client. Our integrations were the simple rest clients.

Here is a guide that integrates [Spring MVC with google protocol buffers.](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/22/using-google-protocol-buffers-with-spring-mvc-based-rest-services)

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb I'm trying to deploy gRPC as eureka instance together with spring boot actuators and I want clients to see gRPC port when they choose the service. My bootstrap.yml looks like this `server:
  port: 8082

eureka:
  instance:
    nonSecurePort: 8083` where 8083 is where gRPC server is started, but what I see is that eureka discovery client registers  itself on 8082.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we override what is set with server.port. Would you create an issue?

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb. The issue was in my configuration.  I've created the [Google RPC](http://www.grpc.io/) boot-starter [here](https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter), your feedback is highly appreciated.